# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mFocusedTextColor in setting up texthintColor

Tags: android, kotlin

I am inflating dynamic TextInputLayout and want to change the texthintColor and use the following but I end up throwing the exception

```
private fun setInputTextLayoutColor(color: Int, textInputLayout: TextInputLayout) {
    try {
        val field = textInputLayout.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor")
        field.isAccessible = true
        val states = arrayOf(intArrayOf())
        val colors = intArrayOf(color)
        val myList = ColorStateList(states, colors)
        field.set(textInputLayout, myList)

        val fDefaultTextColor = TextInputLayout::class.java.getDeclaredField("mDefaultTextColor")
        fDefaultTextColor.isAccessible = true
        fDefaultTextColor.set(textInputLayout, myList)

        val method =
            textInputLayout.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("updateLabelState", Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType)
        method.isAccessible = true
        method.invoke(textInputLayout, true)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
setInputTextLayoutColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary),myTextInputLayout)
```

support library version

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Exception printStackTrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mFocusedTextColor
```

Comment: have you tried with `TextInputLayout::class.java.getDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor")`

Comment: `TextInputLayout`'s field names have changed. `mFocusedTextColor` is now `focusedTextColor`, and `mDefaultTextColor` is `defaultHintTextColor`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it's working after changing "mFocusedTextColor" to focusedTextColor